# Is it possible to force an event update in Qml? And if so how?

Tags: qt, qml

As far as I understand the way qt works is that it goes through a loop where it checks for events and acts accordingly as well as updating the visuals to represent the changes.

What I would like to be able to do is to force that update to fire from qml, this would be especially useful in test cases but may come in handy elsewhere.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is an example test case where this would come in handy:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtTest 1.0

TestCase {

    property bool activated: false;

    Timer{
        id: timer
        interval: 100
        onTriggered: {
            activated = true;
        }
    }

    function test_timer(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 100000 && !activated){
            //force an event update here
            ++i;
        }
        compare(activated, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call the method `update()` of your component ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm self-taught and didn't know about that, how do I do it.


- I tried timer.update() and that throws the error `Uncaught exception: Property 'update' is not a function`


- As well as update(timer) which throws the warning `Update called for a item without content`


Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you need but there is a `wait` function in `TestCase` : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html#wait-method

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @GrecKo, could you add that as an answer so that I could pick it.